# How to rewrite this URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I would like to rewrite this URL:

```
http://localhost/mock/foo.php?lang=eng&userID=2
```

To:

```
http://localhost/apiMethod.pl?lang=eng&userID=2
```

So when I call http://localhost/apiMethod.pl?lang=eng&userID=2 in the browser, it will actually go to http://localhost/mock/foo.php?lang=eng&userID=2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^apiMethod\.pl$ mock/foo.php [QSA]
```